# word that means everyone's views are heard

Tags: synonyms

I'm writing a personal statement, and I have to write about a principle that is dear to me. I was thinking of "righteousness," but I've searched and the meaning of righteousness is not exactly what I'm looking for.  So which word do you suggest I use?

For example, I wanted to share that there was this discussion, but my friends didn't like the idea but were too afraid to speak up, so I helped them speak up.

Comment: Perhaps "putting people at their ease."

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what it is you’re looking for a word to describe. Your title says one thing (vaguely), your first paragraph says a completely unrelated thing (vaguely), and your third paragraph gives an example of a third, completely unrelated, thing.

Comment: You want to say that you believe everyone's opinion is important and should be heard. You actively encourage people not to be embarrassed or feel threatened by their superiors/bosses. Workers and colleagues should be allowed to speak their mind freely without inhibitions or fear of reprimand. You're an **idealist**! (and probably very young too) :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two qualities you mention here, and I do not know a word that truly combines both.

Inclusivity is an ideal which aims at giving a voice to everyone from a sense of democratic idealism.

> ***inclusivity***   noun   ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inclusivity))
>   1.    the fact or policy of not excluding members or participants on the grounds of gender, race, class, sexuality, disability, etc
>
> ***democracy*** ([3rd meaning Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/democracy)) : an organization or situation in which everyone is treated equally and has equal
>   rights.

adjectives inclusive, democratic.

And the second, helping shy people, and championing them so they can fulfil their potential, that would show supportiveness; adjective: supportive.

> ***supportive***  (adjective )  [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/supportive)1.    providing support, esp moral
>   or emotional support.

Synonyms: encouraging, helpful.